# jQuery inputmask date mask display wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm using jquery.inputmask on text field and for unknown reason it display wrong in some mobile devices.

this is the imput line

```
 <input type="text" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" class="form-control" tabindex="2" autocomplete='off' />
```

and this is the mask implement

```
$("#dueDate").inputmask("99/99", {
  "placeholder": "MM/YY"
});
```

the attached image shows the problem, 12/18 shown as 12/81

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrKAt.png)

apprechiate any help.

Comment: what do you mean by "12/18 shown as 12/81" ? Where does this date of december'18 come from ?

Comment: it's the date, credit card date,
december 18 shown as december 81
you can see in the image

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#dueDate').inputmask("99/99", {
    alias: 'datetime',
    inputFormat: 'mm/yy',
    min: moment().add(1, 'M').format('MM/YY'),
    max: moment().add(10, 'Y').format('MM/YY')
});
```